# How to make space between strings using concat() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to concat multiple string using concat() method it works fine but how can i make white space between them

```
<HTML>
    <head>
       <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <label id="label_one" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
       <label id="label_two" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
       <label id="label_three" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
       <script>
           var one = "abc";
           var two = "def";
           var three = one.concat(two)
           var four = three.length;
           var variableLen = one.concat(three, four);
           document.getElementById("label_one").innerHTML = one;
           document.getElementById("label_two").innerHTML = two;
           document.getElementById("label_three").innerHTML = variableLen;
       </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

and my output is

**abcdef6**  I want my output like this **abc def 6** with space after concate and using concate() method of JavaScript not with concate operator(+)

Comment: Not sure why your answer was voted down, other than perhaps the info could have been found elsewhere. In any case, see answer below

Comment: var one = "abc "; Just give space at the end of your string values and then do the concatenation. This is one way

Comment: `var three     = one.concat(' ', two)` .... `var variableLen = one.concat( ' ', three, ' ', four);`

Comment: Actually i want to concat variable if u notice my question my var with the name of three = one.concat(two) at this point value of variable three in abcdef then i am using length properties and value of variable three is length of string then i concat value of variable one with variable three whose value after using concat() is abcdef with variable four whose value after using length property is 6 how could i make space between them if i am using concat operator(+) then simply give space between them but how in concat() method i do the same

Comment: @Raheel. `concat()` takes a variable number of arguments as at least two answers show below. if you want the length of `three` to exclude spaces from concatenated strings, then either work out the strings lengths independently and add together. Or strip the spaces from the string when finding a length: `var four = three.replace(/\s/g, '').length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of doing it is:

```
var one = "abc";
var two = "def";
var three = one.concat(" ", two);
var four = three.length;
var variableLen = one.concat(" ", two, " ", four);
```

However it might be better to use `join` as another answer mentions. On a side note, you might notice that the `concat()` function takes a variable number of arguments. You can achieve this in your own functions like this:

```
function func1() {
  console.log(arguments); // => [1,2,3]
}

func1(1, 2, 3);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 10):

Try this `[one,two].join(' ');`
(Adapt to your needs as necessary, i.e. build an array of strings, then use `join`)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the white space to the concat. I prefer to use '&nbsp' to generate the space.

```html
<HTML>
    <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <label id="label_one" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
     <label id="label_two" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
     <label id="label_three" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
    <script>
      var one = "abc";
      var two = "def";
      var three     = one.concat(two)
      var four= three.length;
      var variableLen = one.concat('&nbsp', three, four);
      document.getElementById("label_one").innerHTML = one;
      document.getElementById("label_two").innerHTML = two;
      document.getElementById("label_three").innerHTML = variableLen;
     </script>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<HTML>
    <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <label id="label_one" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
     <label id="label_two" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
     <label id="label_three" style="color:blue;"></label><br/>
    <script>
      var one = "abc";
      var two = "def";
      var whiteSpace = " ";
      var three     = one.concat(whiteSpace, two)
      var four= three.length;
      var variableLen = one.concat( three,whiteSpace ,four);
      document.getElementById("label_one").innerHTML = one;
      document.getElementById("label_two").innerHTML = two;
      document.getElementById("label_three").innerHTML = variableLen;
     </script>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var one = "abc";
  var two = "def";
  var three     = one.concat(" ",two)
  var four= three.length;
  var variableLen = one.concat(" ", three," ", four);
```